# Edit Xml from web forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is a newbie who needs your help.I have an xml file and I want to edit the value of each element from a web form and generate the editted xml file using rails:Eg. I want to change the Type of book from Hardcover to Softcopy from a web form and after I will generate the new xml file . I imagine I have to import the xml file to my application and my application show me the xml in grid and I will edit it and generate the new xml.
here is the structure of my xml file

```
<null id_ref="null"/>
<Catalog id_ref="A0">
   <Books>
        <Book id_ref="A1">
           <Name>rails</Name>
           <Type>Hardcover</Type>
           <Modifiers>        
               <Modifier id_ref="A2">
                    <Type>B</Type>
                    <Value>15</Value>
               </Modifier>
               <Modifier id_ref="A3">
                    <Type>B<Type>
                    <Value>12</Value>
               </Modifier>        
           <Modifiers>
       </Book>
        <Book id_ref="A4">
           <Name>Ruby</Name>
           <Type>Plastic</Type>
           <Modifiers>        
               <Modifier id_ref="A5">
                    <Type>C</Type>
                    <Value>14</Value>
               </Modifier>
               <Modifier id_ref="A6">
                    <Type>B<Type>
                    <Value>18</Value>
               </Modifier>        
           <Modifiers>
       </Book>
  </Books>
</Catalog>
```

Thank you in advance.

sentana

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562/1228) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5886185/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I'd recommend not storing the data in XML; instead:

1. map out its meaning to tables
2. parse the XML when importing
3. store in a normalized table
4. and edit normally.
5. When needed, you'll generate using the standard XML buildings in rails.

If you do that, you'll have a much better experience in rails.

If you can't, because you don't know the schema, then look at [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org)